# Problem importing individual frames from QuickTime file

Tags: export, image, video

I am having difficulties with a code I am trying to run.  Essentially I want to
`Read` in a large `.mov` video file (60000+frames).
Then take each frame individually, process it (e.g. crop and identify particles, I can do these steps) and `Export` a text file with processing data (can do), plus the cropped image.

I am not sure which functions/the setup to use for reading in a video and exporting an image sequence.  I have looked at `Import` with `.mov` files, and can identify the number of frames in the movie:

```
videof = Import[path <> file <> ".mov", "FrameCount"]
```

as well as view a single frame

```
frame1 = Import[path <> file <> ".mov", {"Frames", {n}}]
```

however there is something wrong in the second line of code; no matter the value of `n` I always get the first image.

Advice is much appreciated.

Comment: `Import[Directory[]<>"eclipse1.mov", {"Frames", 420}]` works here, and as I change the number (420 in this case) I get different images. If you're having trouble, try it with a small movie first and make sure you have the syntax correct.